# Elasticsearch not_analyzed field transform double '$' symbol

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem when I include a double dollar sign symbol in a not analyzed field. When I check the mapping for the type with the following command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/documents/_mapping/document'
```

I get this output for the code field:

```
{
  "documents": {
    "mappings": {
      "document": {
        "properties": {
          "code": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
          },
          // More field mappings
```

If I test the mapping with the following command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/documents/_analyze?field=code' -d "ABC$"
```

I get the following output:

```
{"tokens":[{"token":"ABC$","start_offset":0,"end_offset":4,"type":"word","position":1}]}
```

This is ok because the token has the same value that the data entered in the command. The problem is when I use a double dollar sign like this:

```
 curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/documents/_analyze?field=code' -d "ABC$$"
```

Then I get the following token:

```
{"tokens":[{"token":"ABC4088","start_offset":0,"end_offset":7,"type":"word","position":1}]}
```

It looks like the double dollar sign gets replaced by the number 4088. According to the docs, the not_analyzed index attribute means:

> Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the value **exactly** as specified. Do not analyze it.

Do miss something in the code field mapping to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$$` is a special environment variable in your shell that gets expanded to the ID of the current shell process.

So when running the `curl` command what happens is that the PID of your current shell is resolved and replaces the `$$` variable, hence the `4088` you see instead of `$$`.

Try to issue `echo $$` and you'll see the ID of your current shell.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/documents/_analyze?field=code' -d "ABC4088"
                                                                          ^
                                                                          |
                                          $$ replaced by the ID of your process
```

Try to simply escape the `$` characters and you should be fine

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/documents/_analyze?field=code' -d "ABC\$\$"
```